# Upper Taskbar (Move & Lock) settings missing

Tags: gnome-panel, taskbar

Upper taskbar (Move & lock) settings are gone. A computer icon replaced my shutdown button in upper right corner as well. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're running Gnome Panel 3. You can edit your panel just like before, but you need to hold Alt and right click instead of just right clicking directly. Unfortunately, Ubuntu's indicator applet hasn't been ported to the new gnome-panel yet, so you will need to get creative for some of the missing elements.

If you're interested, you can take a look at a blog post by one of gnome-panel's developers that explains the changes: [gnome-panel is dead,long live gnome-panel!](http://www.vuntz.net/journal/archive/2011/04/13)

Comment: Thank You, I will check it out as soon as I return home & let you know what I find. I will also read the URL you posted here. Thanks again. James

Comment: Oh, BTW,   the URL is not working. Or the info has been removed, but thanks anyways, I will try holding Alt & right clicking again. I will still inform you of the outcome. J.

Comment: No, I'm not using the Gnome 3 panel. Just the Unity Panel in 11.10 stock. Also, when adding any icons to the upper taskbar, the menu for (Move) & (Lock) are not there. Mmm.

Comment: Dylan: indicator-applet has been ported. Jason Conti has it in his PPA: https://code.launchpad.net/~jconti/indicator-applet/gnome3-ppa. @Cominatyalive: there's never been any such menu in Unity. Gnome Panel is the name of the desktop we've used in Ubuntu before the new Unity desktop arrived. Gnome Panel has those menus, and you need to hold the alt-key while right-clicking to display it.

Comment: Sorry, let me clear the air here. Yes, it's called gnome panel. My apologies, you are right. But when I hear the word gnome, it makes me think you are talking about gnome shell. My mistake. Yes, I know all the panels that the earlier Ubuntu Distros had & did not have. Yes, the alt key works. But isn't it the Windows+Alt key & right click in 64 bit? I will see if just using Alt + Right click works tonight. Either way, many thanks to you!   Muchos Gracias!

Comment: ok, I see. So 11.10 is Unity upper task bar, not gnome. Everything below 11.04 is also gnome task bar? And gnome shell's task bar is also unity? or gnome shell task bar?  Mmmmm. Well, that's my take now, or am I still in the dark?   J.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 from 10.04 or previous? 
Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you were using GNOME 2 before Unity (11.10 new desktop environment).

Comment: No & Yes,,, I was using 10.10 before, but did not upgrade, I did a complete re-install & format of the hard drive. I installed 11.10 Oneiric as the first install, and I also have Zorin 5 Ultimate Natty 11.04 installed side by side. Both 64 bit OS's. I have done a compiz --replace this morning when losing my Compiz to unity as my windows manager, but that was it besides the normal updates that I did a few days ago. You know, the normal 136 updates or so that one gets after a clean install.

Comment: Actually, I did have 10.10 installed before Adding Zorin. I used the Zorin partitioner to remove Ubuntu 10.10 and reinstall Zorin side by side with the 11.10. I did have the (Move & Lock) functions for a few days. But now, I cannot even re-size the taskbar, move any icons, lock the taskbar, nothing. When I right click on the taskbar, nothing happens in 11.10

Comment: Yes, and thank you. Holding the alt, or should I say (Super+Alt) then right clicking on the upper bar will open the menu with the task bar properties. I never used gnome shell until the other day & it's been a while since I have been back here. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The panel in 11.10 is a completely different panel from the one used in 10.10. Though they look similar, they are completely different programs and the new one doesn't support moving stuff around, like the old Gnome Panel did. There are good reasons for this, of course, but that discussion is beyond the scope of this answer. The old desktop panels are still available, though. If you want it, you can get it by installing the [gnome-session-fallback](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-session-fallback) package. You will then be able to choose Gnome Fallback before you log in by clicking on the button next to the password field. There are a couple of changes in Gnome Panel 3;

- To edit the panels, you press the alt-key and right-click the panel.
- The system menu has been replaced with a gnome-control-center, which is available from the user menu on the right.
- You no longer have to lock and unlock applets, but you do need to press alt+middleclick to move it (or alt+super+middleclick).

I would recommend that you familiarize yourself with Unity, keeping in mind that it is a different desktop. It's a different workflow, so things will be a little different. It is highly effective to work with, but coming from Gnome Panel, it might require a little getting used to. But the old desktop is still available if you really want it.

Comment: Thank you, and (No), I will stick to using & learning more about Unity. It's not that hard, but there are a few things we have to ask about from time to time. Actually I am quite able to work my way around the new panel. As of today 04/10/12 I'm using gnome shell 3.2 and really like it. Does not get any simpler than this. Once again, Thank you so much.   J.

Comment: I just made a video you might enjoy. It lasts 4m 20s. I performed the same task in Gnome Panel (classic) and in Unity. Same machine and both are 12.04. I really did my best both times: http://ubuntuone.com/6B3OJrY8yfoP08vcoNsulZ